# Joomla Custom-Component Select Field whit Editor

Tags: joomla, editor, custom-component, dropdownbox

im trying to make a dropdown box, from my table (#__projectinfo) where I can choose e.g a article and show him in a editor ready to use, update or save.

The objective is to choose a email body and send it to a user, the select box is to choose the email, but i need the ready to use editor

e.g: http://prntscr.com/jctkrb , like a article editor (see the image)

any question fell free to ask, ty :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sql field of jform to show list of article from your table(#__projectinfo) , You could use something below in your your_form.xml file.

```
<field name="myProjectList" 
       type="sql" 
       default="10" 
       label="Select an article"
       query="SELECT id, title FROM #__projectinfo"
       key_field="id" // Use your respected key_field column
       value_field="title" //Use your respected value_field column
    />
```

Also you will need the editor field in xml to show the article selected.

- After this catch event of javasript for the given field e.g onChange
- Get the value of myProjectList field using getElementById()
- Send the ajax call to fetch the selected id's data
- Then use setText() method on success of ajax to set the info to editor field

Comment: Ok, Ty i will try that :D

Comment: But I dont know how to do all the outher steps :(, can u give me advance?

Comment: Happy to help you but it will need offline discussion , This comment thread will go on if I start to explain here :)

Comment: sure, it's fine to me :)

Comment: ty raVan but i manage to solve the problem :), now i have outher xD